# how to remove comma from string and store in another string

Tags: php

i want to remove comma from a string and store value in another string any idea how to do this.
for sample.

```
$a =  "1,4,3,5";
```

I want to create 4 new string and store value in it like

```
$b = 1;
$c = 4;
%d = 3;
$e = 5;

<?php
$a = "1,4,3,5";
$b = str_replace(',', '', $a);
echo $b;
?>
```

i write this in php but not working how to finish this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do it:

```
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode (',' , '1,2,3,4');
```

A little explanation:

- `explode` ([doc](http://php.net/explode)) splits your string on the given `delimeter` `(',')`, and returns an array of it. so the `explode (',' , '1,2,3,4')` call is returning you the same thing, as if you would write `array('1', '2', '2', '4')`
- `list` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)) maps variables to your array elements. It's more like a language construction, than a function. So it's the same, as if you would do:

  ```
   $parts = explode (',' , '1,2,3,4');
   $a = $parts[0];
   $b = $parts[1];
   ...
  ```

Comment: You are wellcome. feel free to accept the answer (by ticking the symbol on the left side) if you think it was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can first turn the string into an array with `explode`, like this:

```
$a = explode(',', $a);
```

Then each element is one string

eg:

```
$a[0] === '1'
```

Comment: thanx @Andrew :) my question solved by bali's answer anyway thanx for your time :)